# how to hide all div's except one that is associated with a onmouseover element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a list with items. Based on what item I'm hovering over, I want to show only the one div with associated content and hide all the rest.
The list has about 22 items, so there is 22 different div's I need to switch between (show/hide).

Is there some quick solution to accomplish this with jQuery?

This is how I have set it up at the moment as a sarting point:

```
<div id="list-of-items">
    <ul>
        <li id="item1">item1</li>
        <li id="item2">item2</li>
        <li id="item3">item3</li>
        <li id="item...">19-more-items</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content1">content1</div>
<div id="content2">content2</div>
<div id="content3">content3</div>
<div id="content...">...</div>
```

Comment: are the content divs in a container ? or have a class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#list-of-items li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('#content'+this.id.replace('item', ''))[e.type==='mouseenter'?'show':'hide']();
})​;​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/VCGbF/)

**EDIT**

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$(function(){
    $('#list-items li').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('#content'+this.id.replace('item', '')).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/VCGbF/4/)

Comment: I tried out your solution, and it worked just the way I wanted it to, at first.
But i noticed after a bit that I also needed it to hold the last "focused" one on "mouseleave" so I can interact with whatever is in the displayed div. Do you know of any quick fix for that?

Here is a link btw: http://dev.thomaskile.me/?page=test-zone&sub=test-jqry-show-hide

Comment: @ThomasK - Jada, alt er mulig ;) !! is the point to leave the map of Norway and the selected "fylke" visible on mouseleave, if so you could just remove the mouseleave part, I'll edit the answer ?

Comment: yup, Need to leave the active view open so I can click on some links (not there yet) on the other side of the map. But then again, when I go back and hover over another county it works like now...
didn't get it to work...

Comment: @ThomasK - In the last fiddle, the map stays visible, right? And when hovering the menu of counties it changes again, is that not what you'd like it to do ?

Comment: Nøyaktig hva jeg var på utkikk etter :)

Comment: @ThomasK - Der kan du se :) ... as a sidenote, please feel free to accept the answer !

Answer (score 0):

I would class all of your content divs with something like .content-block

```
<div id="list-of-items">
<ul>
    <li id="item1">item1</li>
    <li id="item2">item2</li>
    <li id="item3">item3</li>
    <li id="item...">19-more-items</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="content-block" id="content1">content1</div>
<div class="content-block" id="content2">content2</div>
<div class="content-block" id="content3">content3</div>
<div class="content-block" id="content...">...</div>
```

and in your css set all to display:hide;

Then, just use the following:

```
$(function(){

    $('#list-of-items').each(function(){

       $(this).on('mouseover',function(){
           var cur-id = $(this).attr('id');
           var content-id = cur-id.replace('item','content');
           $('.content-block').hide();
           $('#'+content-id).show();
       });

    });

});
```

Comment: I bet someone would be able to pull this off with a single handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#list-of-items li').mouseover(function() {
    // hide all content divs except `list-of-items`
    $('div').not('#list-of-items').hide();
    // show content div based on current li id
    $('#' + $(this).prop('id').replace('item','content')).show();
});
```

This uses [.mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) to bind the mouseover event [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the `div` containing the `li`s and [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to obtain the `id` property of the current element.

If you added a `class` to the content `div`s you could replace `('div').not('#list-of-items').hide();` with `$('.classofdivs').hide();`

**[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/qTtKe/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your bottom divs this could be a little easier: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/Jfw5B/

```
<div id="list-of-items">
    <ul>
        <li id="item1">item1</li>
        <li id="item2">item2</li>
        <li id="item3">item3</li>
        <li id="item...">19-more-items</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="contents">
<div id="content1">content1</div>
<div id="content2">content2</div>
<div id="content3">content3</div>
<div id="content...">...</div>
</div>​

$('#list-of-items li').on('mouseover', function() {

   $('#contents div').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();

});​
```

If you don't want to wrap them inside something you could do it quite easily with:

```
$('#list-of-items li').on('mouseover', function() {      
   $('div:gt(0)').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `hover` method both will show and hide the corresponding `div` block.

```
$("#list-of-items ul > li").hover(function() {
    $("#" + this.id.replace("item", "content")).toggle();
});
```

​
**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LzkKM/

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#list-of-items ul > li").hover(function() {
  $("#" + this.id.replace("item", "content")).toggle();
});
</script>
</head>


<div id="list-of-items">
<ul>
    <li id="item1">item1</li>
    <li id="item2">item2</li>
    <li id="item3">item3</li>
    <li id="item...">19-more-items</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content1">content1</div>
<div id="content2">content2</div>
<div id="content3">content3</div>
<div id="content...">...</div>
```